# How to get all the System's BroadcastReceiver in an app by packageName?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have the packageName.I can get some infos through the packageName.But What i want is the BroadcastReceiver in the manifest.xml.Is there any way to get them?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to find that is not reported to you by `PackageManager`?

Comment: I can get some receivers through special intents,such Intent.ACTION_SEND.But What i want is to get all the BroadcastReceiver declared in the manifest.xml.Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`getPackageInfo()` on `PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to retrieve the `PackageInfo` object for your desired package, and the `BroadcastReceivers` are listed in the `receivers` field of the `PackageInfo`.

Comment: This can get the ActivityInfo list about receiver.But i can't get the action of BroadcastReceiver through ActivityInfo.       intent.setPackage(packageName).calling queryBroadcastReceivers(intent,0) can get ResolveInfo list about receiver.But the two way can't get  action of BroadcastReceiver.What     i want is not only the receiver's name,but also the receiver's action.Any help?

Comment: ResolveInfo has a field of filter.But i test the filter,the filter is null.So i can't get the action of the filter,i have no any ideas about the problem now.

Comment: @europa: Add `GET_INTENT_FILTERS` to the flags in your `getPackageInfo()` call.

Comment: :Thank you so much.You inspire me to solve this problem.I get the action now.But there is a difference from your idea.I get a filter not null through queryBroadcastReceivers(intent,PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER）..GET_INTENT_FILTERS can't work in my way.

Comment: ：Here is the code of my problem.  PackageManager pManager = getPackageManager();
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setPackage("com.example.testa");
  List<ResolveInfo> infos = pManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent,
    PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
  for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
   Log.i(TAG, info.filter.getAction(0));
  }